# When is the image of a $T$-algebra under $T$ again a $T$-algebra?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Let $T:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ be a [monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) with unit $\eta:1_\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow T$ and multiplication $\mu:T\circ T\Rightarrow T$, and let $(A,\alpha)$ be a [$T$-algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+over+a+monad).

> When is $\big(T(A),T(\alpha)\big)$ again a $T$-algebra?

This is trivially true when the unit is  epic and the multiplication is monic, or when $\alpha$  is monic, but this seems pretty rare.

The motivation here is that $\alpha$ would then be a $T$-algebra-homomorphism from $\big(T(A),T(\alpha)\big)$ to $(A,\alpha)$, in addition to being a structure map. This seems 'morally correct', but I can't see that it's always true off the top of my head.

Comment: I think this is indeed very rare. Have you checked any examples? Say, monoids?

Comment: @ZhenLin I jumped straight from set theory to category theory with very little background in non-categorical algebra; I almost never check examples because there are very few I'm familiar with. If this fails for simple examples I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: @AlecRhea -- regardless of the answer to this particular question, I would highly suggest getting some familiarity with simple examples of categories, like posets and monoids. They're both very intuitive, so you'll be able to gain some comfort with them quite quickly. It's a very worthwhile investment of time, since it's much easier to learn the abstractions if you have some concrete objects to try out the theorems on.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I appreciate the suggestion; I'm currently racing through $2$-dimensional and inner category theory towards the Non-Galoisian Galois theory of Borceux and Janelidze and I don't want to pause unnecessarily until I get there, but once I've fleshed out my understanding of their theory enough to apply it to situations I'm concerned with I fully intend to get a more 'robust' feeling for examples as you suggest.

Comment: Related to the last paragraph: for any object $A$, $(T(A), \mu_A)$ is always a $T$-algebra; and if in addition, $(A, \alpha)$ is a $T$-algebra, then $\alpha : (T(A), \mu_A) \to (A, \alpha)$ is a $T$-algebra-homomorphism.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Interesting, thank you.

Comment: To be honest, you can of course learn however you feel confortable to, but I don't feel very confident in the chances of someone saying they are not comfortable with super basic algebra like monoids to truly understand high-level stuff such as Borceux-Janelidze. It feels like a situation where one ends up with a very superficial understanding of a vast amount of material, and can't use it at all for lack of foundations. I hope I'm wrong and it works out for you, though! (But I would advise a change in your learning method.)

Comment: @CaptainLama You can scan my MO activity to get a feel for my understanding of category theory (I find MSE boring but use it for lower level questions I have), or you can look at the 200+ pages of notes on my researchgate if you’re really ‘concerned’ — to be honest, I was hoping to elicit responses like this from people who took the classical route up ;). I won’t be taking your unsolicited advice because I don’t want to end up with the same perspective on the subject as everyone else, but best of luck to you!

Comment: I have to say, this question in itself is evidence that your intuitions are leading you astray. You can either  learn some examples and use them to check your intuition, or you can take things slow.

Comment: @ZhenLin I’m not sure how this question indicates a deficiency in intuition, Zhen, but I do feel like we’re moving astray of what’s appropriate for the comment section of MSE — if you would like to email me at alecjrhea@gmail.com I would love to hear any opinions or advice you have for me.

Comment: @ZhenLin you really didn't have to say anything, actually. Consider doing that instead when you don't have an answer to a question.

Comment: Whether my post answers the question or not is for the asker to decide, not you. Your answer, while not wrong, lacks even the most basic example of the case where $T$ is an idempotent monad.

Comment: Guys, we're all mathematicians here -- let's leave the 'insulting us' part of the business to the jocks of the world. Vladimir, your answer here is exactly what I was looking for and I appreciate it greatly, hence moving the checkmark over to you. Zhen, I have immense respect for your work in category theory and your thesis is literally at the top of my list of 'references for when I finally need scheme theory', so I really do want to avoid leaving a bad taste in your mouth for answering my question. Thank you both for your contributions; let's get back to the good work of mathematics!

Comment: @ZhenLin Again, I suggest you focus on actually answering questions instead of leaving rude or condescending comments.

Comment: @AlecRhea I have no dispute with the correctness of Vladmir's answer. I even upvoted it. I am annoyed that he thinks my answer is not an answer (but at least I can guess who the anonymous downvoter was) and I am also concerned that you will get the wrong impression about how rare this property is because he says literally nothing about examples or counterexamples. He should have written his comment on my answer as a postscript to his own answer, rather than presuming to teach grandma to suck eggs.

Comment: @AlecRhea I'm annoyed at those using this platform to browbeat people who just want to learn. I think it's great you're going through Borceux-Janelidze, and wish you success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object $A$ has the structure of a $T$-algebra $a\colon TA\to A$ such that $Ta\colon TTA\to TA$ is also a $T$-algebra if and only if the unit $\eta_A\colon A\to TA$ is an isomorphism, in which case $a\colon TA\to A$ is necessarily $\eta_A^{-1}$, and the multiplication $\mu_A\colon TTA\to TA$ is necessarily the isomorphism $T\eta_A^{-1}$.

For the proof, note first that a $T$-algebra is in particular a morphism $a:TA\to A$ of which $\eta_A\colon A\to TA$ is a seciton, i.e. such that $a\circ\eta_A=\mathrm{id}_A$. Let $e_{TA}=\eta_A\circ a\colon TA\to A\to TA$ be the associated split idempotent (it is an easy exercise that $e_{TA}\circ e_{TA}=e_{TA}$).

We can account at this point for the special cases of $a$ being a monomorphism or $\eta_A$ being an epimorphism. Since $a\circ e_{TA}=a\circ\eta_A\circ a=\mathrm{id}_A\circ a=a=a\circ\mathrm{id}_{TA}$ and $e_{TA}\circ\eta_A=\eta_A\circ a\circ\eta_A=\eta_A\circ\mathrm{id}_A=\mathrm{id}_{TA}\circ\eta_A$, either $a$ being an monomorphism or $\eta_A$ being an epimorphism implies $e_{TA}=\mathrm{id}_{TA}$, and hence that $a=\eta_A^{-1}$ are isomorphisms.

Back to the general case, naturality of $\eta\colon\mathrm{id}\Rightarrow T$ implies $e_{TA}=\eta_A\circ a=Ta\circ\eta_{TA}\colon TA\to TTA\to TA$. Thus for $Ta\colon TTA\to TA$ to be a $T$-algebra, and in particular for $Ta\circ\eta_{TA}=\mathrm{id}_{TA}$ to hold, it is necessary that $e_{TA}=\mathrm{id}_{TA}$, so again $a=\eta_A^{-1}$.

Conversely, $a=\eta_A^{-1}\colon TA\to A$ is a $T$-algebra if and only if $a\circ Ta=a\circ\mu_A$, which post-composition with $\eta_A$ renders  equivalent to $Ta=\mu_A$, which follows from the fact that $\mu_A\circ T\eta_A=\mathrm{id}_{TA}$ implies $\mu_A=(T\eta_A)^{-1}=T\eta_A^{-1}=Ta$.

Comment: Very cool, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it rarely happens.

Here is a simple non-example.
Consider the so-called maybe monad on $\textbf{Set}$.
(It is the monad induced by the forgetful functor from the category of pointed sets to the category of sets.)
We might write $T X = X \amalg \{ * \}$ but this gets confusing when we iterate so (exploiting the axiom of regularity...) let me instead write $T X = X \amalg \{ X \}$.
Then $T^2 X = X \amalg \{ X \} \amalg \{ T X \}$.
An algebra structure on $T X$ is a map $\beta : X \amalg \{ X \} \amalg \{ T X \} \to X \amalg \{ X \}$ such that $\beta (x) = x$ for $x \in X \amalg \{ X \}$.
But if $\alpha : X \amalg \{ X \} \to X$ is any map whatsoever then $T \alpha (x) \ne x$ when $x = X$.
So $T \alpha$ cannot be an algebra structure on $T X$.

Comment: It's not that rare because the condition is equivalent to the unit being an isomorphism. So whenever you have an adjunction, it identifies certain key objects on the left-hand side, like sheaves among presheaves in the adjunction of presheaves and bundles. It also holds for all algebreas of a monad if and only if it is associated to a coreflective subcategory, e.g. the cateories of commutative monoids or commutative groups as subcategories of the categories of monoids or groups,

Comment: I consider the property of being an idempotent monad to be rare.